# What is the difference between the 'ea' and 'ēa' in both history and pronounciation in Old English?

Tags: english, diphthongs

I am aware that these two are essentially the same diphthong, just one is short and one is long, but I heard that they originated separately, so if it is so, what did they each originate from and what vowel do other Germanic languages have in places where English uses them? Another question is that if 'ēa' is /ɛ:/, then would not 'ea' just be /ɛ/? But then what is the difference between that and just normal 'e'? I am a bit confused here.